# path expected join error! JPQL inner join query many to many example

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I was writing a query where i was fetching the list of books with the particular author_id, book and author are mapped as many to many relation book entity contains id, name and set of authors and author entity contain name and id. I created an intermediatory table writes which contain author_id and book_id. i have not created any writes entity class, its in the mysql db

What is wrong with the following query, i am getting an `path expected join error!`

```html
@Query (SELECT b.name from Book b inner join writes w on b.id=w.book_id where w.author_id = ?1)
List<Book> findByAuthorId(Integer AuthorId);
```

My book entity is

```html
package golive.data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name="book")
public class Book implements java.io.Serializable{

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 private Integer id;
 
 @NotNull
 @Column(name="name")
 private String name;


 @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinTable(name = "writes", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "book_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "author_id") })
 private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<Author>(); 


 public Set<Author> getAuthors() {
  return authors;
 }

 public Integer getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setAuthors(Set<Author> authors) {
  this.authors = authors;
 }

 public void setId(Integer id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
 
 
}
```

My author entity is

```html
package golive.data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name="author")
public class Author implements java.io.Serializable{

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 @Column(name="id")
 private Integer Id;
 
 @NotNull
 @Column(name="name")
 private String name;
 
 public Integer getId() {
  return Id;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setId(Integer id) {
  Id = id;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
 
}
```

I dont have any writes entity, it there in my database

Comment: Could you share your entities? Does your entity writes has an attribute named book id or it just have an attribute of Book? If thats the case you must update your query since using book_id is agains JPQL.

Comment: @bhdrkn , i dont have writes class , its only in database, i have added my book and author class

Comment: I have already shown you how to do this in response to your duplicate question. You should close this duplicate and update the first question if required.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `nativeQuery = true` to Query annotation. And change your query to native form. If your database names are also Book and writes and column names are correct this should work.

```
@Query ("SELECT * from Book b inner join writes w on b.id=w.book_id where w.author_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<Book> findByAuthorId(Integer AuthorId);
```

### Update

Star is added to query. You cannot select only bookName to book object. But you can select book names to a String list.

```
@Query ("SELECT b.name from Book b inner join writes w on b.id=w.book_id where w.author_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> findByAuthorId(Integer AuthorId);
```

Comment: do i need to add any gradle dependency for nativeQuery, its showing some syntax error as `invalidMemberValuePairs` , in above @query line, i am writing query line in the bookrepository interface

Comment: @ratnesh according to documentation there should be, http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query. Which version of spring data are you using?